# Mac has lost view of certain files, but they still exist

Tags: macos, finder

So I am having trouble with a mac. After the antivirus removing a virus it got, all the files in the User Directory folders Applications, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Movies has disappeared. If you go to All My Files all the files are still there.

Files do exist and in the Get Info tab they show that they exist in that location
[image]
Files Don't appear in the in the Music Folder
[image]
I have tried using `sudo mdutil -E /`
I get the message that indexing has been enabled.

When I try to do `sudi mdutil -E /Users/`
I get the message: No Index.

When I do `ls -la ~/Music`:

```
total 32
drwx------+ 8  teagansmith staff 272 22 Dec 19:25 . 
drwxr-xr-x+ 30 teagansmith staff 1020 25 Apr 15:51 .. 
-rw-r--r--@ 1  teagansmith staff 15364 4 Mar 20:17 .DS_Store 
-rw-r--r-- 1   teagansmith staff 0 8 Aug 2012 .localized 
drwxrwxrwx 5   teagansmith staff 170 3 Dec 2012 GarageBand 
drwxrwxrwx 157 teagansmith staff 5338 22 Dec 19:32 bens music
drwxr-xr-x 11  teagansmith staff 374 25 Apr 16:38 iTunes
drwxr-xr-x 111 teagansmith staff 3774 21 May 2013 music
```

Comment: Open your `Terminal.app`, then enter `cd ~/Music; ls -la`. What does it output?

Comment: total 32
drwx------+   8 teagansmith  staff    272 22 Dec 19:25 .
drwxr-xr-x+  30 teagansmith  staff   1020 25 Apr 15:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 teagansmith  staff  15364  4 Mar 20:17 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--    1 teagansmith  staff      0  8 Aug  2012 .localized
drwxrwxrwx    5 teagansmith  staff    170  3 Dec  2012 GarageBand
drwxrwxrwx  157 teagansmith  staff   5338 22 Dec 19:32 bens music
drwxr-xr-x   11 teagansmith  staff    374 25 Apr 16:38 iTunes
drwxr-xr-x  111 teagansmith  staff   3774 21 May  2013 music

Comment: Thanks. Next time please just [edit] the question to add that info! So… when you do `chflags nohidden ~/Music/iTunes`, does the folder show in Finder again?

Comment: No. The folder doesn't show in Finder.